# Add space between SliverAppBar and SliverList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have a SliverAppBar and below it, a SliverList.

The first SliverList item is too close to the SliverAppBar. I'd like to add some spacing between, whether via a bottom margin below the SliverAppBar or above the SliverList.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[SliverPadding](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverPadding-class.html) - wrap this widget around it.

your solution should look something like the this:

```
SliverPadding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
  sliver: SliverAppBar(...)
)
```

OR

```
SliverPadding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  sliver: SliverList(...)
)
```

Comment: MediaQuery.removePadding helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64405574/10329023