# Remove the top padding from ScrollBar when wrapping ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am trying to add `ScrollBar` to `ListView` in Flutter but the `ScrollBar` still have padding on top when scrolling to the start of the `ListView`.

I included a snapshot of the application so you can understand the problem better. it`s in the indicator of the scrollbar widget the top padding should not be there ,so the start of the scrollbar indicator should touch the bottom edge of the blue DrawerHeader.

### here is my code:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sc = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);

    final res = MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Driver App'),
        ),
        body: null,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    radius: Radius.circular(30),
                    thickness: 10,
                    controller: sc,
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: false,
                      controller: sc,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item 2'),
                          onTap: () {
                            // Update the state of the app.
                            // ...
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item 2'),
                          onTap: () {
                            // Update the state of the app.
                            // ...
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item 2'),
                          onTap: () {
                            // Update the state of the app.
                            // ...
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item 2'),
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                        ),
                        ...
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), // Populate the Drawer in the next step.
        ),
      ),
    );

    return res;
  }
}
```

### result when scrolling position is 0:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]
use **MediaQuery.removePadding** widget with **removeTop: true**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sc = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);

    final res = MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Driver App'),
        ),
        body: null,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                    context: context,
                    removeTop: true,
                    child: Scrollbar(
                      radius: Radius.circular(30),
                      thickness: 10,
                      controller: sc,
                      isAlwaysShown: true,
                      child: ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: false,
                        controller: sc,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                              // Update the state of the app.
                              // ...
                            },
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                              // Update the state of the app.
                              // ...
                            },
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                              // Update the state of the app.
                              // ...
                            },
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                            },

                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                            },

                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                            },

                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {
                            },

                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), // Populate the Drawer in the next step.
        ),
      ),
    );

    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW I got an error when I tried to run your solution the context should be coming from MaterialApp Widget  So I moved the home part to other widget to fix this error.

Comment: Thanks! The questions is why does it has padding in the first place? Not for all ListViews this padding appear by default. Very weird..

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar padding is set as follows:

```
  ScrollbarPainter _buildMaterialScrollbarPainter() {
        return ScrollbarPainter(
          color: _themeColor,
          textDirection: _textDirection,
          thickness: widget.thickness ?? _kScrollbarThickness,
          radius: widget.radius,
          fadeoutOpacityAnimation: _fadeoutOpacityAnimation,
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).padding,
        );
      }
```

The solution to remove the padding in your case would be to place your Scaffold inside the SafeArea.

```
  home: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Driver App'),
      ),
```

Comment: thank you, Wrapping `Scaffold` with a `SafeArea` did the trick, but I find @karzan-kamal Solution more convenient.

Comment: Yes, his answer was correct, I hadn't seen MediaQuery.removePadding yet, it seemed very useful.

Comment: SafeArea did not work for me but MediaQuery.removePadding worked. return MediaQuery.removePadding(
                context: context,
                    removeTop: true,
                    child: ListView.builder(........

Comment: where do i place the _BuldMaterialScrollBarPainter method?

Comment: @codeboi Nowhere, _buildMaterialScrollbarPainter is a function of the flutter's internal api, it's the way it set the Scrollbar padding, just put your Scaffold inside of a SafeArea or use MediaQuery.removePadding() widget.

Comment: but what if instead of removing the padding someone wanted to change the padding values

Comment: @codeboi i think you could wrap the scroll bar with MediaQuery.removePadding() and put it inside a padding widget, that way u could define what padding it will be.